# Google Maps MarkerClusterer v3 and jQuery autocomplete cause error

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-autocomplete, markerclusterer

I am trying to implement a [Google Maps MarkerClusterer](https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html) example and everything seems to be working fine, until I try to add a couple some jQuery autocomplete script.  As soon as I include the following code, the MarkerClusterer stops working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#SaleCity").autocomplete( "../home/ajaxSelectCity/");
    $("#subjectproperty").autocomplete("../home/ajaxSelectSubject/");
});
```

These are the inputs on the page for the autocomplete:

```
  <input    type="text" 
        id="subjectproperty"                
            style="margin-left:0px;" 
            placeholder="Subject Property" 
            class="g2" />
  <input    type="text" 
        id="SaleCity" 
            placeholder="Municipality" 
            style="margin-left:0px;" 
            class="g2" 
            required 
            data-regex="^[a-zA-Z. ]+$">
```

The error message that I receive is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autocomplete' of null
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks. The page in question can be found at [results.ptax.ca](http://results.ptax.ca)

Comment: Do you have a div with id="subjectproperty" on your page and and one with id="SaleCity" (that are accessible when the document ready event fires)?  Do they have an autocomplete property?

Comment: I don't have divs with id="subjectproperty" and id="SaleCity", but I do have <input> controls with those ids.  I have edited the question to now show the input controls.

Comment: OK, should have said "HTML elements". Do they have autocomplete properties when the jQuery document ready event handler runs?  Are you loading the [JQuery UI script](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by that comment.

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote on this question.  I'm just trying to figure this stuff out.  I am loading the JQuery UI script, and you can see this by looking at the sources on the page.

Comment: I shouldn't need to look at an external link (although it doesn't hurt to provide one). The question should stand alone.

Comment: I did provide a link to the actual page which is at results.ptax.ca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarketClusterer must be overriding the default $ reference for jQuery.  I had to pass the reference into the function like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {      
  jQuery("#SaleCity").autocomplete( "../home/ajaxSelectCity/");
  jQuery("#subjectproperty").autocomplete("../home/ajaxSelectSubject/");
});
```

All good now.